# How to convert Spark map keys to individual columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark 2.3 and scala 2.11.8.

I have a Dataframe like below,

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| ID  | Name | Desc_map                                |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | abcd | "Company" -> "aa" , "Salary" -> "1" ....|
|  2  | efgh | "Company" -> "bb" , "Salary" -> "2" ....|
|  3  | ijkl | "Company" -> "cc" , "Salary" -> "3" ....|
|  4  | mnop | "Company" -> "dd" , "Salary" -> "4" ....|
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Dataframe,

```
----------------------------------------
| ID  | Name | Company | Salary | .... |                         
----------------------------------------
|  1  | abcd |   aa    |   1    | .... |
|  2  | efgh |   bb    |   2    | .... |
|  3  | ijkl |   cc    |   3    | .... |
|  4  | mnop |   dd    |   4    | .... |
----------------------------------------
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is your dataset that contains:

```
+---+----+----------------------------+
|ID |Name|Map                         |
+---+----+----------------------------+
|1  |abcd|{Company -> aa, Salary -> 1}|
|2  |efgh|{Company -> bb, Salary -> 2}|
|3  |ijkl|{Company -> cc, Salary -> 3}|
|4  |mnop|{Company -> aa, Salary -> 4}|
+---+----+----------------------------+
```

You can get your desired output through:

```scala
data = data.selectExpr(
  "ID",
  "Name",
  "Map.Company",
  "Map.Salary"
)
```

Final output:

```
+---+----+-------+------+
|ID |Name|Company|Salary|
+---+----+-------+------+
|1  |abcd|aa     |1     |
|2  |efgh|bb     |2     |
|3  |ijkl|cc     |3     |
|4  |mnop|aa     |4     |
+---+----+-------+------+
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I'll not the knowing the name of the keys at runtime. Any ways to parse it dynamically?